# JSON array into handlebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

i have a json object as

```
[ "id", "birthday", "companymsgsthisperiod", "companythisperiodend", "cust_attr_boolean", "subscribed", "testgroup", "usermsgsthisperiod", "userthisperiodend" ]
```

now i would like to add this type of json object using handlebar into a file as

```
<div>/*json*/</div>
```

Can anyone help me to get through it?

Comment: That's just a plain JS array of strings. Not JSON.

Answer (score 7):

What you have there is an array. I guess from the [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) that you can use the **each** block helper

```
<div>
  {{#each dataArray}}
  <div>{{this}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried using each block but its not working it is giving depth error.

Comment: Did you happen to get a solution for this? I am also trying to print a n array of strings in handlebars. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Finally it may satisfy your need.

[image: tryhandlebarsjs.com - screenshot]

Comment: Is not `{{#data}}` as `{{#each data}}`

Comment: Do you have any documentation link to verify ? I just tried in http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ and its not working..

Comment: Don't take me wrong I am just verifying your answer to learn myself.

Comment: Thats pointing to [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) thats different one. but question is tagged with [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), in handlebars your synax is wrong. it will not work.

Comment: `{{.}}` this is just printing the array. To iterate you need to use `{{#each`. In stack overflow, answer with link alone is not encouraged.

Comment: I just understand your problem.I  just re edit the code. Check out the link again.

Comment: Please try to include written and formatted code, and not just a screenshot of code.